# whenever gem how to specify start and end

Tags: ruby, cron, whenever

How can I specify start and end of the job?

example execute every 5 minutes start at 5am and end at 10pm. Is this possible in whenever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cron syntax for this would be

```
*/5 5-22 * * * sh ./script.sh
```

---

Explanation

```
 */5 5-22 * * * sh ./script.sh
  \   \    \ \ \_every week day
   \   \    \ \__every month
    \   \    \___every day
     \   \_______every hour between 0500 (5 AM) and 2200 (10 PM)
      \__________every 5 minutes
```

---

Here's how to do it in whenever

```rb
# schedule.rb

every '*/5 5-22 * * *' do
  command "echo 'crontab syntax is useful'"
end
```

Comment: good answer but i want to used whenever gem so that i will not maintain the crontab by itself. I want to update using rails gem

Comment: Please see my edit for how to accomplish this using the whenever gem.